# Error in Actionscript 3 - "TypeError: Error #1010: A term is undefined and has no properties."

Tags: actionscript-3

I cannot for the life of me find any undefined term in this code. The compiler isn't returning a line, just an error that says, "TypeError: Error #1010: A term is undefined and has no properties.
    at Snakev1_fla::MainTimeline/update()"

Here's the code:

```
    function update(e:Event):void
{
    if (keys[Keyboard.RIGHT])
    {
        directions["right"] = true;
    }

    if (keys[Keyboard.LEFT])
    {
        directions["left"] = true;
    }
    if (keys[Keyboard.UP])
    {
        directions["up"] = true;
    }
    if (keys[Keyboard.DOWN])
    {
        directions["down"] = true;
    }
    var i:int = segments.length - 1;
    while (i > 0)
    {
        segments[i].y = locations[locations.length - 6][1];
        segments[i].x = locations[locations.length - 6][0];
        i--;
    }
    if (directions["right"])
    {
        head.x +=  5;
    }
    if (directions["left"])
    {
        head.x -=  5;
    }
    if (directions["up"])
    {
        head.y -=  5;
    }
    if (directions["down"])
    {
        head.y +=  5;
    }
    directions["up"] = false;
    directions["down"] = false;
    directions["left"] = false;
    directions["right"] = false;

    locations[locations.length][0] = head.x;
    locations[locations.length][1] = head.y;

    trace(locations);

    if (head.x < food.x + food.width / 2 + head.width / 2 && head.x > food.x - food.width / 2 - head.width / 2 && head.y > food.y - food.height / 2 - head.height / 2 && head.y < food.y + food.height / 2 + head.height / 2)
    {
        food.x = Math.random() * 490;
        food.y = Math.random() * 490;

        var body:part = new part();

        body.x = locations[locations.length - 6][0];
        body.y = locations[locations.length - 6][1];
        body.width = head.width;
        body.height = head.height;
        segments[segments.length] = body;
        addChild(segments[segments.length-1]);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At least one of your variables are null. You can set a breakpoint at the start of the function and step line by line until it crashes, which should tell you the problem line, and problem variable.

You can also put

```
trace (keys == null);
trace (directions == null);
//and so on for every variable
```

at the start of your function. The program will still crash but it will trace every variable, and at least one of them should return true.

Comment: Perfect, thanks. I'm completely new to actionscript and didn't know about the debug mode. It ended up being a problem with the locations list - adding a new list element works differently than I'm used to in Python

Comment: I didn't catch those 2 lines of code. You cannot push to a list that way using an Array. However you can push that way if you use a Vector instead. It's almost identical to an Array except that it is strictly typed. `var fruits:Vector.<Fruit> = new Vector.<Fruit> ()`.